# Unable to store SplQueue object properly in memcache in ZF2..?

Tags: php, queue, memcached

I am creating a data queue using SplQueue php class and storing the queue in memcache :

```
$queue = new \SplQueue();
$queue->enqueue($data);
print_r($queue);
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('memcached')->setItem('key', $queue);
$queue = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('memcached')->getItem('key');
print_r($queue);
```

Last `print_r` is giving blank result like this :

```
SplQueue Object
(
    [flags:SplDoublyLinkedList:private] => 4
    [dllist:SplDoublyLinkedList:private] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

But first `print_r` is giving generated queue as expected. This code is working fine on my local system but generating above mentioned issue on production server.

Note:- Memcahced version is same on both machines 1.4

Any help will be appreciated..!!

Answer (score 1):

While googling, i found [here](http://php.net/manual/en/spldoublylinkedlist.serialize.php) that it's a issue with serialization of `SplDoublyLinkedList` class in PHP version lower that 5.4. `SplDoublyLinkedList::serialize` was not working on production server (as server was running with PHP 5.3) and there is no alternative solution to do that except upgrading the PHP version to 5.4.